# Incompatible types error with Fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm trying to add a fragment to my main activity. When I type `fragment = new CrimeFragment();` I get an `Incompatible types` error.

I tried casting `new CrimeFragment();` to a `Fragment`, but that didn't work.

```
package com.adamanteusstudios.officesmostwanted;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;


public class MostWantedActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_most_wanted);

        //getting fragmentManager
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);

        if(fragment == null){
            ***fragment =  new OffenseFragment();***
            fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment).commit();
        }
    }



}
```

The error says:

> incompatible types
>   required: android.v4.support.app.Fragment
>   found: com.adamanteusstudios.officesmostwanted.OffenseFragment

How do I fix this error?

Comment: check what `OffenseFragment` extends. Probably the non `.support.v4.` version, this can easily happen when you import the wrong type, so check the imports for `android.app.Fragment`.

Comment: OffenseFragment extends FragmenActivity and android.app.Fragment was already imported. Are you saying that I should have imported something different?

Comment: OffenseFragment extends FragmentActivity. I used the auto import and it add android.app.Fragment. I replaced it with android.app.support.v4.app.Fragment and I was able to instantiate OffenseFragment. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

In class `OffenseFragment.java` replace

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

with

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```